# how to roll back SQL Server updates?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

A botched update that failed halfway is causing issues, I was wondering how I could roll back an update for SQL Server? Secondly, I was wondering if there is any other place (aside from)  **Setup Bootstrap\Log**  where  I could see which updates were installing and which one failed. I use SQL Server 2012

Comment: Do you mean, you installed a CU or SP and you want to uninstall it ?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the software (meaning, I installed a Service pack and some other updates, I didn't really read all of the items, I remember some were service packs and some were patches)

Comment: Did you check Programs and Features and see if your updates/service packs are listed there?

Answer (score 1):

That path is the full source of SQL installation info and is a goldmine.

The best way to deal with a failed patch is to find out what happened; either in those files or the SQL ERRORLOG. It's most commonly SSISDB in an availability group or a filestream error (fixable with add/remove programs on the instance to run a repair).

I'm not sure if you can rollback an unsuccessful patch but it's easy to reapply the patch and try again, they resume very very well. After its successfully installed then they're easy to uninstall with add/remove programs again.

There aren't many good reasons to uninstall an SP or CU for SQL though. They're pretty important.

Comment: Hi Cody, Thanks for your answer. When you say "SQL ERRORLOG" you mean the ERRORLOG file in that same folder? Also, add/remove program , as far as I've assumed, only allows you to uninstall the entire program, not just a patch/update. And I wanted to uninstall a SP or CU only install it again.

Comment: If I remember right, 2008 or 2008 R2 was first version that allowed uninstalling updates like service packs.

Comment: @LearnByReading ERRORLOG is in another folder where SQL is installed; it's not part of the patching process but if the installation failed because SQL was unable to start then SQL will store its information about why in there. Yes Add/Remove can be used on SPs and CUs.